# Sum of infinite series $ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{2}{3}x^3+\cdots $

Tags: sequences-and-series

If 0 < x <1 then sum of infinite series

$$ \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{3}{4}x^4+\cdots $$

1. $ \log \frac{x+1}{1-x}$
2. $\frac{x}{1-x}+ \log(1-x)$
3. $\frac{x}{1-x}+ \log(1+x)$
4. $\frac{1}{1-x}+ \log (1-x)$

My attempt: I computed series, of each of these option non matched the required series. I need suggestions here. Thanks

Comment: Your series satisfies $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Only one of the proposed solutions satisfies both this conditions.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac r{r+1}x^{r+1}=\sum_{r=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{r+1}\right)x^{r+1}$$

$$=\sum_{r=1}^\infty x^{r+1}+\left(-\sum_{r=1}^\infty\frac{x^{r+1}}{r+1}\right)$$

Now the first summation is clearly a Geometric Series and for the second, use $$\ln(1-y)=-\sum_{u=1}^\infty\frac{y^u}u$$

Comment: I was just about to write this answer.

Comment: We know the standard maclaurin expansions of fxns given in the option. But none was matching the required series. Why was that

Comment: maybe the expansions were written in a different form but the final answer both converge to are same

Comment: @BigBang, Observe that log series expansion starts with exponent $=1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee for second u shud get ln (1-y)-y

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac {1} {1 - x}.$$ Differentiate to get $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n + 1) x^n = \frac {1} {(1 - x)^2},$$ and multiply by $x$ to get $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n x^n = \frac {x} {(1 - x)^2}.$$ Integrate to get $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {n} {n + 1} x^{n + 1} = \frac {1} {1 - x} + \log (1 - x),$$ which is what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)= \frac{x^2}{2}+ \frac{2}{3}x^3+\frac{3}{4}x^4+...... $$
$$f'(x)=x+2x^2+3x^3+.......$$
$$xf'(x)=x^2+2x^3+3x^4+.....$$
$$f'(x)(1-x)=x+x^2+x^3+.......=\frac{x}{1-x}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$$
now integrate it backwards to get $f(x)$

Answer (score 1):

Studying the pattern we find that it can be interpreted as $(x^{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{2})+(x^{3}-\frac{x^{3}}{3})+\ldots$
Using Maclaurin Series expansion (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html) for $\frac{1}{(1-x)}$ , we get $1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\ldots$ and for  log(1-x) , we get  $-(x+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{3}}{3}+\ldots)$. So multiply $x$ with expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and adding it to the expansion of log(1-x) gives us the required series. So answer is the option 2.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\sum_k \frac{k+1}{k} x^k  =\sum_k x^k + \sum_k \frac{x^k}{k}$ and $\frac{x^k}{k} = \int_{0}^{x} y^{k-1} dy$

Hint 2: use Geometric series

Answer (score 0):

The series can be written as: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n+1}x^{n+1}$. Try the Taylor expansion of these 4 candidates and compare the coefficients with above infinite series.